# Is there a way to multiply the 2d matrices of a 3d array by a scalar in R?

Tags: r, arrays, matrix

I have a 2x2x10 array of identity matrices, created with

```
arr = array(diag(2), dim=c(2,2,10))
```

I'm looking to multiply each 2x2 matrix within that array by a scalar `c(1:10)`

```
z = arr[,,1:10] * c(1:10)
```

However, I'm getting unexpected results. The first three 2x2 matrices of `z` shown below

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    0
[2,]    0    8

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9    0
[2,]    0    2
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Relevant: [Array - vector multiplication in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223050/array-vector-multiplication-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to `rep`licate to make the lengths same

```
arr[,,1:10] * rep(1:10, each = length(arr[,, 1]))
```

or else 1 gets multiplied by the first element of `arr[, , 1]` 2 with the second element of `arr[,, 1]` and due to recycling the elements of shorter vector is recycled until the `length` of `arr[, , 1:10]`

Comment: I knew there was a reason for the pattern I was seeing in my output. I just couldn't figure it out. Thank you so much though! This is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

`sweep()` is designed for this:

```
sweep(arr, 3, 1:10, `*`)

, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    0
[2,]    0    2

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    0
[2,]    0    3

...
```